# fstab drive auto-mounted to wrong (non-existent) dev

Tags: linux, mount, fstab

I ran into a curious problem today.

`ls /media/Personal` would yield `ls: reading directory .: Input/output error`.

According to `mount`, that folder was mounted from `/dev/sdb1`. Yet according to `blkid`, I only had drives on `sda1` and `sdc1`.

`umount`ing it (resulted in `segmentation fault` but was successful),
then running `mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /media/Personal` brought everything back to normal.

The question is, **how could this have possibly happened in the first place?** No manual `mount`s were performed since boot (really, not much of anything was done since boot), and `fstab` is as follows:

```
UUID=0119497c-ae50-42e0-9015-e557bf71398e /media/Business ext4 defaults,nofail 0 0
UUID=a36fd062-5cbf-4e4b-abd5-926f84287cf9 /media/Personal ext4 defaults,nofail 0 0
```

It's certainly odd that I ended up with `sdc` and not `sdb`. Moreso, there was nothing wrong with the "Business" mount (same type of drive, no SMART errors on either). This is on Raspbian Jessie.

Comment: Well, you _couldn't_ possibly have had `sdc` if there wasn't a `sdb` before it. Does this happen every time, or just this once?

Comment: It's only happened once so far!

Answer (score 0):

Raspbian? So the drives are connected via USB probably.

My guess is the drive had been registered as `/dev/sdb` and mounted as it should. Then there was something like power fluctuation that caused the drive to go offline and online right after, but as `/dev/sdc` this time. The old, nonexistent device remained formally mounted.

I made a test in my Kubuntu. I recreated this scenario with my first try, no sweat. I got `Input/output error` but no `segmentation fault`. I suppose Kubuntu handles such situations more gracefully, hence the difference.

There is one thing that bothers me though. You claim you had to manually mount `/dev/sda1` to set things right afterwards. In my scenario `/dev/sda1` would be the other (unaffected) drive and you should have mounted `/dev/sdc1`. For now I cannot explain how you could have your drive mounted as nonexistent `/dev/sdb1`, still available as `/dev/sda1`, while the other drive apparently being `/dev/sdc1` from the very beginning (mounted all the time without issues).

So this answer can't fully explain what happened in your case (unless you made a typo and it was `/dev/sdc1` you had mounted by command). Nevertheless the answer may be useful for future users with similar problem.